# Electronics Election - Votes Remaining

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Not the most world-shattering misbehaviour, but while voting in the Electronics Moderator elections, I am informed that:

1. Initially, that I have three votes...
2. After placing my first vote, that I have two votes remaining
3. After placing my second vote, that I have one vote remaining

What is so odd about that, you may ask?

There are only two candidates, so I can only vote twice!

Could I suggest that initially, instead of `NumberOfVotes = 3` that `NumberOfVotes = min( 3, NumberOfCandidates )` ?

*Mutter: thought I was posting on meta.stackexchange*

Comment: If you want to delete and repost, I can help you with that. I don't think I will facilitate a move because I don't think this will go over well on the meta because it's a condition that is not encountered often and the programmers have 'much bigger fish to fry'. (sometimes its hard to even get basic features implemented)

Comment: ok, leave it her. Thx

Comment: I had a CM look at it and there you go.

Answer (score 2):

[As per our Q1 roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), we're currently doing work on automating site elections. As a part of that work, this will be addressed — we'll update y'all once we've gotten to this.

Comment: Thanks... and thanks @VoltageSpike :-)

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in our post on MSE relating to [new moderator election voting functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979/51), from now on users will be able to vote for all candidates in an election, and we are thus no longer going to be showing any notifications relating to number of votes remaining.